# How to tag a CI/CD build on success?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-tag, gitlab-ci.yml

I want to (git) tag a state of the branch with successfully finishing a CI/CD pipleine

E.g.

- compile
- test
- package
- deploy

if all this stages worked well, I would like to have a tag

/branchName/stableDeploy/

How can this be done with gitlab-CE?

Of course I could do the opposite, means first tag and afterwards build, but on many commits, I would like to be able to cherry-pick only that tags, which successfully processed the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with `after_script`:

```
deploy:
  ...
  after_script:
    - >
      if [ $CI_JOB_STATUS == 'success' ]; then
        create your tag
      else
        what to do on failure
      fi
```

Comment: thank you...    
"create your tag" do you have working commands for the local git repo?

Comment: I don't know, maybe

   ` - tag=${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}-mytag
    - git tag $tag
    - git push origin $tag`